# How to make only text of react bootstrap table header clickable

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Code:

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField="test" isKey dataSort>Column</TableHeaderColumn>
```

With this the whole area of the column is clickable, I just want the text and the chevron to be clickable, how can I achieve that.

[This image show that the whole area is clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpFMe.png)

Please help, i am stuck on this

[This is the output HTML generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blYya.png)

Comment: Wrap the text and chevron in a span tag and bind onClick to the span tag.

Comment: I also thought about it but how can i achieve it, it's generated with this line of code @Envision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css to disabling clicking on some elements using [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)
property:

`pointer-events: none;`

This is definition of `none` value of property:

> **none:** The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

It seems `TableHeaderColumn` generate some html with specific class, something like this:

```
 <th class="sort-column">
```

your can write css:

```
 .sort-column{
 pointer-events:none;
```

}

to disable clicking on whole column, but as this will also disable clicking on text you need to reset pointer events property off child element(text)

```
 .sort-column-child{
   pointer-events:auto;
 }
```

This is how you will use it:

```
   <TableHeaderColumn dataField="test" isKey dataSort><span class="sort-column-child">Column</span></TableHeaderColumn>
```

Comment: it's already clickable, as the default sorting is inbuilt in the react-bootstrap table. The issue is that i dont want the whole area to be clickable, just the text

Comment: What is the structure of generated html?

Comment: Please refer to the out put image in the main ques @Vlado Pandžić

Comment: Please see my solution. I checked it and it works. Idea is that you set pointer-events:none on parent(whole column) to disable clicking, and then enable it on child (text) using: pointer-events:auto;